How to split values ​into separate lines in ListBox WinForm?
How to split values ​​into separate lines in ListBox WinForm, but keep them in one line
foreach (var bus in allBus)
{
    string busRouteInfoText = $"Название маршрута: {bus[1]}\n" +
                      $"Номер автобуса: {bus[0]}\n" +
                      $"Дата отправления и прибытия: {bus[2]} - {bus[3]}\n" +
                      $"Стоимость билета: {bus[4]}";
    listBox_BusRoute.Items.Add(busRouteInfoText);
}

Tried using \n, changing ListBox properties, but no luck. Perhaps there are some other ways to display information.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/owner-draw-listbox-control-in-windows-forms-and-C-Sharp/

How to add multiline Text to a ListBox item?

It is really not clear what you want ("split into separate lines but keep in one line" is very confusing). If you want to add multiline text items to the ListBox, then follow Jimi's link. This would invalidate my answer (except for the raw string part).

You can split the string at the \n in order to create an array of strings. The ListBox requires individual items.
listBox_BusRoute.Items.AddRange(busRouteInfoText.Split('\n'));

You can also assign the string array to the DataSource of the ListBox
listBox_BusRoute.DataSource = busRouteInfoText.Split('\n');

Note that you can add any type of items to a ListBox. They don't need to be strings; however, a string is always added as a single item, even if it has multiple lines.
You could also use a raw string introduced in C# 11.
string busRouteInfoText = $"""
    Название маршрута: {bus[1]}
    Номер автобуса: {bus[0]}
    Дата отправления и прибытия: {bus[2]} - {bus[3]}
    Стоимость билета: {bus[4]}
    """;
listBox_BusRoute.Items.AddRange(busRouteInfoText.Split("\r\n"));
// or
listBox_BusRoute.DataSource = busRouteInfoText.Split("\r\n");

The left edge of the string is determined by the position of the terminating """. I.e., in this example the lines of the string contain no leading spaces.
Probably your editor inserts \r\n as line separator. Therefore I split by CR/LF.

Replace object ListBox to ListView.
